# Agregar y descontar valores a un diccionario con funciones

Tags: python-3.x, lista, funciones, diccionarios

Tengo los siguientes diccionarios:

```
 dic_ingredientes = {'TOMATE': 5, 'LECHUGA': 2, 'HAMBURGUESA': 10, 'CARNE': 1, 'ESPÁRRAGOS': 8, 'PAN': 10, 'PAPA': 5, 'CEBOLLA': 12}

 dic_recetas = {'HAMBURGUESACASERA': ['HAMBURGUESA', 'TOMATE', 'PAN'], 'PASTELDECARNE': [' CARNE', 'PAPA', 'CEBOLLA'], 'ENSALADAESPECIAL': ['LECHUGA', 'ESPÁRRAGOS', 'TOMATE']}
```

A partir de estos diccionarios donde el `value` de `dic_ingredientes` es el stock inicial, se pide hacer un `input("Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER:")`

`PASTELDECARNE= [CARNE, PAPA, CEBOLLA] # Donde cada ingrediente corresponde a una unidad, que luego se descuenta en el dic_ingredientes si preparo una receta (sólo admite una receta al input)`

**En la consola:**

```
Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: PREPARAR PASTELDECARNE
Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles
TOMATE 5
LECHUGA 2
HAMBURGUESA 10
CARNE 0
ESPARRAGOS 8
PAN 10
PAPA 4
CEBOLLA 11
Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: PREPARAR PASTELDECARNE
*** No se puede hacer PASTELDECARNE porque falta CARNE ***
Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles
TOMATE 5
LECHUGA 2
HAMBURGUESA 10
CARNE 0
ESPARRAGOS 8
PAN 10
PAPA 4
CEBOLLA 11
Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: REPONER LECHE CARNE HUEVOS CARNE PAN
Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles
TOMATE 5
LECHUGA 2
HAMBURGUESA 10
CARNE 2
ESPARRAGOS 8
PAN 11
PAPA 4
CEBOLLA 11
Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: PREPARAR OMELETTE
*** Lo sentimos pero no preparamos OMELETTE ***
```

Al agregar ingredientes al input `REPONER LECHE CARNE HUEVOS CARNE PAN`, se debe actualizar el stock en `dic_ingredientes`.

También se deben omitir los ingredientes que no están en el diccionario como LECHE Y HUEVOS en el ejemplo de arriba y en caso que una receta no este en `dic_recetas` se debe imprimir `*** Lo sentimos pero no preparamos AAA ***`

A partir de esta explicación, se pide generar una función para reponer ingredientes (sumar al diccionario) y otra función para preparar la receta (descontando los ingredientes del diccionario)
Para terminar el programa con la palabra `STOP` se detiene.

Tengo las siguientes funciones, me faltaría la de **preparar la receta**(no sé si están bien formuladas):

```
def printStocks():
    print("Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles")
    for k, v in dic_ingredientes.items():
    print(k, v)

def reponerIngredientes(lista_ingredientes):
    reponer_ingredientes = lista_ingredientes.split()[1:]
    for ing in lista_ingredientes.split()[1:]:
        dic_ingredientes[ing] = int(dic_ingredientes[ing])+1         
    return(lista_ingredientes)
```

Comment: tengo un ejercicio parecido ejemplo al chequear que no se puede preparar receta porque falta x ingredientes , me descuenta igual el resto de ingrediente que si esta :( y no deberia porque la receta no fue prerada por falta de ingredientes , me pueden ayudar en ese :( (es un ejercicio parecedio el que estoy haciendo solo que es otro rubro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como consejo trata de enfocar tu pregunta en algo más especifico, pues describes todo tu problema y parece que quieres ayuda con todas las funciones, solo hago la respuesta por que se ve que ya tienes las otras funciones.

Para hacer la función de `preparar` solo necesitamos obtener los valores de la receta y luego iterar en ellos y verificar que cada uno se encuentre en el diccionario de ingredientes y luego solo descontamos.

```py
def preparar(receta): #recibe como parametro el nombre de la receta
    if receta in dic_recetas: #verificamos que exista la receta
        ingredientes = dic_recetas[receta] #obtenemos los ingredientes
        for ing in ingredientes: #recorremos la lista de ingredientes
            if dic_ingredientes[ing] == 0: #si es 0 no se puede preparar
                return f"No se puede preparar por que falta {ing}"
            else: descontar(ing) #descontamos
        return "Listo!" #todo salio bien
     #si no existe decimos que la receta no fue encontrada
    else: return "receta no encontrada"
```

Para hacer la función descontar es lo mismo que tu función `reponerIngredientes()` pero en vez de sumar, restas. En este caso hice algo diferente, pues mi función `descontar()` recibe como parámetro 1 ingrediente y por tal razón hago la llamada dentro del `for` para que descuente cada ingrediente.

```py
def descontar(ingrediente):
    if ingrediente in dic_ingredientes: #verificamos que existe
        #como los valores del diccionario son de tipo entero podemos restar directamente
        dic_ingredientes[ingrediente] -= 1
        return "Listo" 
    else: 
        #decimos que no existe el ingrediente
        return f"No existe el ingrediente {ingrediente}"
```

Puedes implementar esta función ó cambiar el `+` por `-` de tu función anterior pues hace *lo inverso*. De ti depende de cuantas llamadas quieres hacer y que tan *eficiente* quieras hacer tu código. Para el caso que elijas modificar tu función colocarías la llamada ala función después del ciclo `for`.
**probamos**

```py
opc = input("Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: ").lower()
if opc == "preparar":
    printStocks()
    receta = input("Ingrese la receta: ").upper() #PASTELDECARNE
    print(preparar(receta))
    printStocks()
```

**resultado**

```
Ingresa la receta que quieres o REPONER: preparar
Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles
TOMATE 5
LECHUGA 2
HAMBURGUESA 10
CARNE 1
ESPÁRRAGOS 8
PAN 10
PAPA 5
CEBOLLA 12
Ingrese la receta: PASTELDECARNE
Listo!
Stock actual de ingredientes disponibles
TOMATE 5
LECHUGA 2
HAMBURGUESA 10
CARNE 0
ESPÁRRAGOS 8
PAN 10
PAPA 4
CEBOLLA 11
```

Comment: Gracias Christian, en la función `preparar(receta)` se puede agregar dentro de la función, una función `dic_recetas()` donde descargo el diccionario desde un csv

Comment: sip, pero creo que seria conveniente hacer eso al iniciar el programa, para así no estar descargando los datos cada vez. Si tienes más dudas es mejor hacer otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) añadiendo los detalles, dudas e inconvenientes que tengas